# in C++, is the clock steady status compiler dependent?

Tags: c++

I use the following code, to output the steady status of 3 clocks

```
#include <chrono>
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>

template <typename C>
void printClockData ()
{
    using namespace std;

    cout << "- precision: ";
    // if time unit is less or equal one millisecond
    typedef typename C::period P;// type of time unit
    if (ratio_less_equal<P,milli>::value) {
        // convert to and print as milliseconds
        typedef typename ratio_multiply<P,kilo>::type TT;
        cout << fixed << double(TT::num)/TT::den
             << " milliseconds" << endl;
    }
    else {
        // print as seconds
        cout << fixed << double(P::num)/P::den << " seconds" << endl;
    }
    cout << "- is_steady: " << boolalpha << C::is_steady << endl;
}

int main()
{
    std::cout << "system_clock: " << std::endl;
    printClockData<std::chrono::system_clock>();
    std::cout << "\nhigh_resolution_clock: " << std::endl;
    printClockData<std::chrono::high_resolution_clock>();
    std::cout << "\nsteady_clock: " << std::endl;
    printClockData<std::chrono::steady_clock>();
}
```

compile with g++, outputs

[image]

compile with intel icl outputs

[image]

Why the difference?

Comment: When you wonder about some library feature, the first to do is to check the documentation. What does the documentation say, if anything?

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf I don't understand. Which doc say the they are compiler dependent? I can not find such saying here http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/header/chrono

Comment: `high_resolution_clock` has the choice (per platform, per implementation) to either implement `steady_clock` or `system_clock`, and `steady_clock` is always steady.  Intel probably has an implementation available for that platform using a `high_resolution_clock` that uses `steady_clock`.

Comment: Further, GCC more than likely does not offer a `high_resolution_clock` for that platform that uses `steady_clock`.  You can use the compiler flag `--enable-libstdcxx-time=rt` to ensure all clocks are steady, but there is performance penalty associated with it in applications that use a single thread (GCC 4.8).

Comment: @zackery.fix Thank you, I understand

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it is, for the `high_resolution_clock`. As the C++ standard says:

> **20.12.7.3 Class `high_resolution_clock`**
>
> Objects of class `high_resolution_clock` represent clocks with the shortest tick period. `high_resolution_clock` may be a synonym for `system_clock` or `steady_clock`.

For example [Visual C++ 2015](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh874757.aspx) has it typedef'ed to `steady_clock`, Intel probably also.

For `steady_clock` the standard explicitly sets `is_steady` to true.

Comment: libstdc++, on the other hand, currently has `using high_resolution_clock = system_clock;` (file `chrono`, line 776).

Comment: Oh, I understand. The doc really tells, I saw it, but I was silly then. Thank you very much!